# Oracle Client vs Oracle Instant Client on Linux!

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, oracle-11g, linux, client

to have the following setup on a Linux box:

- SQLPlus
- client library (oci.dll)!!!!
- ORACLE_HOME is set for users

is **Oracle Instant Client** enough or I need to have the **Oracle Client** installed on the box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only need to run SQLPlus, grab "*Instant Client Package - Basic*" and "*Instant Client Package - SQL Plus: Additional libraries and executable for running SQL Plus with Instant Client*" from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxsoft-082809.html & install them.

oci.dll is a windows file, so I have no idea what could be achieved by installing that on Linux.

unzip the files into a location of your choice & set LD_LIBRARY_PATH and PATH to point to that directory. If you need any further help after that, edit your question.